# Creating an image from a webpage

Tags: java, python, phantomjs, javafx-webengine

I'm working on a way to detect defacement on my website. The idea is to crawl the whole website and for each page, take a screenshot or render the website as an image and compare it with the last time the page has been checked.

I'm looking for a way to convert a whole webpage (HTML, CSS, JS) into an image, like a screenshot, no matter the language is (but I would prefer Java, Python or C#)

I need it to be fast and usable on a server.

I already tried the folowing in Java:

- CssBox, but the rendering isn't good enough (no JS)
- Selenium Web Driver, but it's way too slow (Time to open firefox, display the page etc...) and not usable without GUI

I think a solution would be a kind of wrapper for a web engine but I didn't find anything about that (at least in Java). I've been told PhantomJS would fit for this need, is it right?

The perfect result would be to create something like that: http://www.page2images.com/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a browser which you can control via a script or command line options like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). The documentation contains examples how to make screenshots from URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked offer some good rest API that perform the task: it's not a viable option for you?

Comment: This solution is not free and involves one connection for each page, and I have 100+ sites

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is your best bet. Depending on your page content (ie. JS libraries, etc) it might take some time, but you could automate this with a script to run nightly via cron. Or using screen.

It has a rich language of assertions and simulated mouse events, and ways to regression-test and/or monitor the state of a set of pages.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

With no GUI, it's probably not possible to do something like this.

If you're not too tight on the GUI and related things, you can use the [JavaFX Webview](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and take a screenshot of the node using the following code

```
WritableImage image = webView.snapshot(null, null);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
....
```

References:

[WebView#snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage))

[SwingFXUtils#fromFXImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#fromFXImage(javafx.scene.image.Image,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage))